# Can I manually rearrange the nodes created by Arrange -> Advanced -> Mermaid

Tags: mermaid, draw.io

I can create the edge graph but would like to move some of the pieces around so it's not so horizontal.

Mermaid...

```
Graph TD;
1 --> 28 ;
2 --> 23 ;
3 --> 8 ;
4 --> 9 ;
5 --> 33 ;
6 --> 40 ;
7 --> 28 ;
8 --> 33 ;
9 --> 8 ;
10 --> 27 ;
11 --> 33 ;
12 --> 9 ;
13 --> 28 ;
14 --> 27 ;
15 --> 36 ;
16 --> 34 ;
17 --> 11 ;
18 --> 44 ;
19 --> 36 ;
20 --> 34 ;
21 --> 11 ;
22 --> 11 ;
23 --> 8 ;
24 --> 8 ;
25 --> 34 ;
26 --> 43 ;
27 --> 33 ;
28 --> 33 ;
29 --> 51 ;
30 --> 28 ;
31 --> 28 ;
32 --> 33 ;
33 --> 43 ;
34 --> 33 ;
36 --> 27 ;
37 --> 19 ;
38 --> 20 ;
39 --> 21 ;
40 --> 53 ;
41 --> 42 ;
42 --> 33 ;
43 --> 0 ;
44 --> 33 ;
45 --> 13 ;
46 --> 14 ;
47 --> 15 ;
48 --> 12 ;
49 --> 16 ;
50 --> 17 ;
51 --> 33 ;
52 --> 27 ;
53 --> 33 ;
54 --> 29 ;
```

Draw.io render
[image]

All of it
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to move individual elements of a mermaid diagram. You could try and do a combination of graphs with some being TD and some being LR - but Im not sure

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the vertical distance in your graph by increasing the number of hyphens for each line. If you increase the number of hyphens to three or four you might get the kind of vertical distance you are looking for.

You can do this by using find and replace in a text editor to replace "-->" with "--->" or "---->".

I'm not familiar with draw.io but if you paste the following text into the editor window on [mermaid.live](https://mermaid.live) you can export the png below or svg equivalent.

```
graph TD
1 ----> 28 
2 ----> 23 
3 ----> 8 
4 ----> 9 
5 ----> 33 
6 ----> 40 
7 ----> 28 
8 ----> 33 
9 ----> 8 
10 ----> 27 
11 ----> 33 
12 ----> 9 
13 ----> 28 
14 ----> 27 
15 ----> 36 
16 ----> 34 
17 ----> 11 
18 ----> 44 
19 ----> 36 
20 ----> 34 
21 ----> 11 
22 ----> 11 
23 ----> 8 
24 ----> 8 
25 ----> 34 
26 ----> 43 
27 ----> 33 
28 ----> 33 
29 ----> 51 
30 ----> 28 
31 ----> 28 
32 ----> 33 
33 ----> 43 
34 ----> 33 
36 ----> 27 
37 ----> 19 
38 ----> 20 
39 ----> 21 
40 ----> 53 
41 ----> 42 
42 ----> 33 
43 ----> 0 
44 ----> 33 
45 ----> 13 
46 ----> 14 
47 ----> 15 
48 ----> 12 
49 ----> 16 
50 ----> 17 
51 ----> 33 
52 ----> 27
53 ----> 33
54 ----> 29
```

[image]